# how to Reduce Requests from website for images which are dynamic

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql, windows-hosting

We have hosted a website containing dynamic images, coming from a folder.(c# is my back end) Load time of page is around 13 sec, which I watched in tools.pingdom.com .
To reduce that load time We used handler to call all the J query files in single request, which works great. but we are unable to find a solution to make a request from website to get all the images in single request. Since the images are dynamic we can't go with sprites.
Please give us a solution.

And also please suggest us which way of storing images makes site performance fast (in DB/Folder).

Comment: How often do these dynamic images change?

Comment: Have you considered lazy loading the images via AJAX requests - this will make the page 'feel' faster, also a 13 second load time based on images sounds like you haven't optimised the images - what size are the images and are they PNGs etc. Better yet - do you have the site URL (or is it local)

Comment: Hi Alexander.. thanks for comment.. Site is designed in such away that admin can change image when ever he want. Up to my knowledge it wont be changed for a month minimum.

Comment: Hi  Graham Ritchie... Thanks for your comment. i didn't no about lazy loading.. can you please refer me about that. coming to image we reduce as much as we can. http://www.f1usavisa.com is my site..

Answer (score 0):

Thankq @Graham Ritchie, As peryour comment i have played with jquery and found a solution.
i.e i have added my src to data-src. aftermy pageload i shifted my data from data-src to src. so that my page loadtime isreduced. now my page is loading between 3-5 sec.